# Will Pop Scope is not working with Overlay Widget

Tags: flutter, overlay

I had prepared a custom overlay widget, that I am aiming to use anywhere in the app, so I made a global Overlay entery that will get its value when overlay is created and then i have created a function to remove that overlay that i thought to call on Onwill pop , but the problem is that the will pop scope is not being called for this overlay widget or if i use any widget inside it with overlay.

```
bool isOverlayOnScreen = false;
late OverlayEntry? globaOverlayEntry;

showOverlayWidget({required BuildContext context,required Widget widgetToDisplay})async{
  OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);

  globaOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      maintainState: true,
      builder: (context){
    return WillPopScope(child: widgetToDisplay, onWillPop: ()async{
      print("Print Will of Stack widget called----2");
      return true;});
  });
  isOverlayOnScreen = true;

  overlayState.insert(globaOverlayEntry!);
}

void removeGlobalOverlay() {
  globaOverlayEntry!.remove();
  globaOverlayEntry!.dispose();
  isOverlayOnScreen = false;
  globaOverlayEntry = null;
}

void showWidgetScreen(BuildContext context,Widget widgetToDisplay) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return widgetToDisplay;
    },
  );
}
```

Can anyone provide me with the reason and solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

WillPopScope won't work with showDialog, but instead you can use the return of the function like this:

```
showDialog(
       ...
       
      ).then((value) {
       /// Your logic here
});
```